# Save Media(Video) etc files from installed app.(Android or IOS)

Tags: android, video, download, youtube, apk

So there is this app that can be installed, and requires subscription, i have one, but the content keeps delecting over some time and i would like to save it locally(not netflix or hbo). But im unsure how to do it apart from screenrecording and screenshots which are inefficient and laggy.

Theres no video link and no way to obtain it since its not a site to inspect elements or so.
Being online content, decompiling the apk would not help. Unless i can decompile it and run with proper credentials(which i do not know how to do).
Wireshark bugs the app.

Comment: You answer is too general to be answered. An app can apply any measures it want to protect downloaded local content like obfuscation, encryption... Some download it already in that form so capturing the data on network level may not be helpful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.